# Changing text in binary files

Tags: file-corruption, binary-files, isolinux

While looking inside a binary file in a text editor, I came across some readable text. I have executed the binary before, and know that the readable text is echoed on screen. Is it possible to remove or change some of the text without corrupting the binary file?

Example:

[image: example binary file]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, as long as the change you want to make is of identical length.

Also, you must use an appropriate editor for binary....a standard text editor will not work.

If you are Linux based, my favorite is bvi....vi interface with both text and numeric content.  Replacement is character by character.

Comment: Does Notepad++ count as standard?

Comment: @Krii Np++ isn't a binary editor.